# Evaluating a series of criteria with nested ifs in R - is there a better way?

Tags: r, coding-style, package, control-flow

Much of my work revolves around diagnostic tests for tuberculosis.  As you might imagine, it's handy to be able to quickly evaluate and validate the outputs of those tests.  I wrote a function that does just that, [here](https://gist.github.com/969492) (pared down for clarity).  In short, it takes the numeric results from the test and produces the manufacturer-specified interpretation.

This function works well for me - I've validated it against thousands of tests, and it's fast enough for anything I throw at it.  I'd like to bundle it and a couple of similar functions into a package for wider use, however, and I'd like to get some feedback on it before I do so:

1. The function depends on a great big for loop wrapped around nested if-else functions.  It isn't especially elegant and the dread `for()` undoubtedly damages my credibility with some (ahem), but it works.  Is there a better approach to this?  If so, is it sufficiently better to warrant re-writing Code That Works?
2. The criteria in the above function are for interpretation of the test in North America; the rest of the world follows slightly different standards.  I'd like to have those available, as well.  I'm considering having a separate, non-exported function for each.  The various data checks (excluded from the above gist) would continue to live in the main function, which would then call the specified subfunction.  Does that sound reasonable?
3. Any other suggestions or advice?  Style, code organization - anything at all.

I realize I should probably just push this baby bird out of the nest, but I work mostly in a vacuum and so am a bit nervous.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Edit: in case you missed the link to the gist, [this is the function I'm talking about](https://gist.github.com/969492).

---

As requested, [sample test data](https://gist.github.com/969641).

Comment: The potentially changing criteria are the hardcoded values such as 8, .25, etc?  Or the terms, e.g. intermediate?  Or something else?

Comment: Can you post some example data and expected results so we can test any changes we make?

Comment: Actually, it's been awhile since I had looked at the global criteria - it looks like it's just the last set of criteria (lines 23-26) that's unique to North America.  That would be easy enough to toggle off and on.  But it's also possible that I'd want to add other sets of criteria for different groups (e.g., immunocompromised patients), or alternative criteria that have been developed in studies.

Comment: Regarding #1, a well-written for loop is often faster than a `*apply` approach (for loops were slower in past versions of R). A vectorized solution will be fastest.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for your help.  Probably bit off a little too much with this one question, though the control flow was the big problem.  I'm going to work on this a bit more and see if I still have questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited to reflect comments and to validate against test data**

You can avoid any type of loop or `if` altogether and simply use R vector subscripting:

```
qft.interp <- function(nil, tb, mitogen, tbnil.cutoff = 0.35){

  # Set a tolerance to avoid floating point comparison troubles.
  tol <- .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5

  # Set up the results vector
  result <- rep(NA, times = length(nil))
  result[nil+tol > 8.0] <- "Indeterminate"
  result[is.na(result) & (tb-nil+tol > tbnil.cutoff) & 
          (tb-nil+tol > .25*nil)] <- "Positive"
  result[is.na(result) & (tb-nil+tol < tbnil.cutoff | tb-nil+tol < .25*nil) &
        !(mitogen-nil+tol < 0.5)] <- "Negative"
  result[is.na(result) & ((tb-nil+tol < tbnil.cutoff | tb-nil+tol < .25*nil) &
          mitogen-nil+tol < 0.5)] <- "Indeterminate"
  result
}

all(with(tests, qft.interp(nil, tb, mitogen)) == tests$interp)

[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Sample data added!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think you need to trim out some of those [i] instances to get a fully vectorized solution but I agree this is the cleanest way. See my lines below that would not work in a comment.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that later criteria can overwrite earlier ones: for example, there's a test in the sample data with nil = 9.41, tb = 6.73, and mitogen = 10. That's original set (correctly) as an indeterminate, but later changed to a negative. The `if()` flow of the original prevents this.

Comment: @Matt Parker: You could add `is.na(result)` to each of the later criteria.  Then you would preserve the precedence.

Comment: @Joshua: Indeed it does!  Just validated that against a larger dataset, and the results came back just the same as before.

Comment: @Matt Parker and @Joshua Ulrich, thank you for the suggestion to add `is.na(result)` to tests.  @DWin, D'oh - now fixed :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
result[ nil + (tol > 8.0)] <- "Indeterminate"
result[(tb - nil + (tol > tbnil.cutoff) ) & (tb - nil + (tol > .25 * nil) )] <- "Positive"
result[ (tb - nil + (tol < tbnil.cutoff) )| (tb - nil + (tol < .25 * nil)) &
                         !(mitogen - nil + tol < 0.5) ] <- "Negative"
result[ (tb - nil + (tol < tbnil.cutoff) ) | (tb - nil + (tol < .25 * nil) ) & 
                          (mitogen - nil + (tol < 0.5) ) ] <- "Indeterminate"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Note the comments by Matt Parker that the criteria are not MECE, so you should add `!is.na(result)` to some of your tests.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @Andrie: Good that you identified that. I did wonder if they really were mutually exclusive. I do think tightening up the code (as you di  will make it easier to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the `for` loop, use `apply` with a function written to return the interpretation.

Comment: `apply` is just a pretty form of `for` and usually is no faster

Comment: Right, which is why I tend to forget about it.  Speed isn't really relevant here, anyway - it's already fast enough.  Pretty is good, though.